# Get corresponding time and value from json using Django (Python 2)

Tags: json, django, python-2.x

The following is a sample of the JSON that I'm fetching from the source. I need to get certain values from it such as time, value, value type. The time and value are in different arrays and on different depth.

So, my aim is to get the time and value like for value `1`, I should get the timestamp `1515831588000`, `2` for `1515838788000` and `3` for `1515845987000`.

*Please mind that this is just a sample JSON so ignore any mistakes that I may have made while writing this array.*

```
{
  "feed":{
  "component":[
     {
        "stream":[
           {
              "statistic":[
                 {
                    "type":"DOUBLE",
                    "data":[
                       1,
                       2,
                       3
                    ]
                 }
              ],
              "time":[
                 1515831588000,
                 1515838788000,
                 1515845987000
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
 },
"message":"",
"success":true
}
```

Here is a function, that I have written to get the values but the timestamp that I'm getting on the final step is incorrect. Please help to resolve this issue.

`get_feed_data()` is the function that is giving the above JSON.

```
# Fetch the component UIDs from the database
component_uids = ComponentDetail.objects.values('uid')
# Make sure we have component UIDs to begin with
if component_uids:
    for component_uid in component_uids:
        # Fetch stream UIDs for each component from the database
        stream_uids = StreamDetail.objects.values('uid').filter(comp_id=ComponentDetail.objects.get(uid=component_uid['uid']))
        for stream_uid in stream_uids:
            feed_data = json.loads(get_feed_data(component_uid['uid'], stream_uid['uid']))
            sd = StreamDetail.objects.get(uid=stream_uid['uid'])
            for component in feed_data['feed']['component']:
                for stream in component['stream']:
                    t = {}
                    d = {}
                    stats = {}
                    for time_value in stream['time']:
                        t = time_value
                    for stats in stream['statistic']:
                        for data_value in stats['data']:
                            print({
'uid': sd, value_type:stats['type'], timestamp=t, value=data_value
})
```

Comment: Can you specify values you are getting frou your function?

Comment: @Krystofee I get the last value of time from the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it dome using lists. I simply append the data in a list and call it later in a loop using the index and fetch the corresponding date and time.